# How can I label my \newlist from other than 1

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I want to label my 'Question' from 5. But I can only start from 1 now. It seems `\setcounter{enumi}` can only work for `{enumerate}`.

```
\newlist{Question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Question]{label=\textbf{Question \arabic*}}
\section*{Problem 1}
\begin{Question}
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
  \item content of question 5\\
  \item content of question 6
\end{Question}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `enumitem` package has `start=` option for the lists. It does take care of the counter value, so `start=5` will really start at `5` and not set the `enumi` counter to `5` which will be increased with the first item to have the value of `6` then.

In my opinion, the `leftmargin=*` option should be used here, to prevent strange margins.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{Question}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Question]{label=\textbf{Question \arabic*},leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
\section*{Problem 1}
\begin{Question}[start=5]
  \item content of question 5\\
  \item content of question 6
\end{Question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: damn you're quick

Comment: @Moriambar: I used the 'load - code' force ;-)

Comment: It's also my opinion :o)

Comment: @Bernard I was posting my answered and his popped up. You answered some 30seconds later :P